# NameSpace Autoinclude erroring on only 1 specific class

Tags: php, namespaces

assume these are in seperate files.

```
<?php
namespace aName;

function importerLoader($class)
{
  $elements =  explode('\\',$class);
  if (count($elements) == 2 && $elements[0] == __NAMESPACE__)
  {
    $filename = $elements[1].'.php';
    if (file_exists($filename) )
    {
      error_log("calling".$filename);
      require($filename);

    }
    else
    {
      error_log("File does not exist ".$filename);
      return false;
    }
  }
}

spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__.'\importerLoader');

<?php
namespace aName;

class Question
{

    ...
    protected function importAnswers()
    {
      foreach($this->QuestionData as $answer)
      {
        $this->answerObjects[$index] = new Answer($answer);//Fatal error
        also tried
$this->answerObjects[$index] = new Answer::answerFactory($answer);//Fatal error

      }
    }

    ...
    public static function questionFactory($question)
    {
      $returnMe = false;
      if (self::validQuestionType($question))
      {
        switch ($question[0]->qtid)
        {
          case 1:
            $returnMe = new QuestionType1($question);
            break;
          case 2:
            $returnMe = new QuestionType2($question);
            break;
        }
        return $returnMe;
      }
    }

}

<?php
namespace aName;

class Answer
{
    ...
    public static function answerFactory($answer)
    {
      $returnMe = false;

      switch ($answer->qtid)
      {
        case 1:
          $returnMe = new AnswerType1($answer);
          break;
        case 2:
          $returnMe = new AnswerType2($answer);
          break;
        default:
          $returnMe = new Answer($answer);
          break;
      }
      return $returnMe;
    }
}
```

and finally

```
<?php
namespace aName;

class Quiz
{
    ...

    function importQuestion($question)
    {
      //insert newly created into it's proper ordering int he question objects table.
      $this->_questionObjects[$question[0]->question_order] = Question::questionFactory($question);

    }
}
```

Note: the autoloader works for ALL other classes.
The Answer.php class does not. I get a Fatal Error. I have checked typos. it is all in the same directory.
When Quiz imports a question the factory works. but when the question makes an answer i get a fatal error. 
Note that the quiz is an object in another object that was called byt he autoloader.

I get

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'aName\Answer' not found in C:\<A PATH>\Question.php on line 315
```

i am thoroughly lost. it even includes the file but it does not recognize the class. I can only guess it is a namespacing issue but I cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue. I don't know why but the editor was saving that file at the incorrect encoding. swapped it and it works now.